# Как закрывать предыдущие открытые маркеры открыванием следующих?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="untitled.css">
  </head>
  <style>

      #map{
      margin: 30px;
      border: 3px dashed red;
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 90%;
      height: 500px;
}

  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap(){
  var element = document.getElementById('map');
  var options = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: {lat: 48.356574, lng: 24.416949}
  };

  var myMap = new google.maps.Map(element, options);

  var markers = [
  {
      coordinates: {lat: 48.348905, lng: 24.428091},

      info: '1' 
    },

    {
    coordinates: {lat: 48.922498, lng: 24.710013},
    info: '2'
    }
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    addMarker(markers[i]);
  }


  function addMarker(properties) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: properties.coordinates,
    map: myMap
  });

  if(properties.image){
    marker.setIcon(properties.image)
  }

  if(properties.info){
    var InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: properties.info
    });
  }
  marker.addListener('click', function(){
      InfoWindow.open(myMap, marker);
    });

  }
}

    </script>




    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBGQAOhQmjaXvRGLdbgS5ZHkenIcmzRzbk&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

метод Open открывает информационные окна над маркерами. вопрос как сделать так чтобы при открытии другого маркера окно открытого автоматически закрывалось. Библиотека имеет метод close() но никак не получается его применить. условия пробовал уже по разному все равно.

Comment: добавить в глобальный scope ссылку на текущий, открытый маркер.... при вызове следующего маркера, вызывать метод close() у текущего

Comment: В конце, перед строчкой `InfoWindow.open(myMap, marker);` возможно прописать закрывание сразу всего что открыто? Даже не узнавая, который был открыт до этого - закрыть тупо всё, а уже потом открыть то, что нужно.

Comment: пробовал но не получилось. возможно не так делаю(